# Cant get GetItem to work properly with goamz dynamodb

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I was following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.01.html) tutorial, and set up the table using Python, and I can get item with Python but not with golang. What am I doing wrong?

I made my table like this (almost copy and paste from the tutorial):

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')

table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Movies',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)
```

I loaded the data like this (in Python):

```
my_item = {"year": 1999, "title": "MyMovie", "info": {"Plot": "DynamoDB"}}
table.put_item(Item=my_item)
```

And when I read data (in Python):

```
response = table.get_item(Key={"year":1999,
                        "title":"MyMovie",
                    }
    )
print response
```

My output is:

```
{u'Item': {u'info': {u'Plot': u'DynamoDB'}, u'year': Decimal('1999'), u'title': u'MyMovie'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'C8I2Q46K06T030INBCFN35RELVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'C8I2Q46K06T030INBCFN35RELVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'content-length': '93', 'server': 'Server', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amz-crc32': '4025342458', 'date': 'Wed, 02 Nov 2016 18:20:14 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0'}}}
```

My golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/goamz/goamz/aws"
    "github.com/goamz/goamz/dynamodb"
)


func main() {

    access_key := "MyAccessKey"
    secret_key := "MySecretKey"

    auth := aws.Auth{AccessKey: access_key, SecretKey: secret_key}

    server := &dynamodb.Server{Auth: auth, Region: aws.USWest2}

    desc_ptr, err := server.DescribeTable("Movies")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    primary_key, err := desc_ptr.BuildPrimaryKey()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    table := server.NewTable("Movies", primary_key)

    my_key := dynamodb.Key{HashKey: "1999", RangeKey: "MyMovie"}

    result, err := table.GetItem(&my_key)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Printing Result")

    for k, v := range(result) {
        fmt.Println(k, *v)
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Printing Result
title {S title MyMovie [] }
year {N year 1999 [] }
```

This is missing everything besides `title` and `year` that I provide. What am I missing?

Edit:

My `go` version:

```
go version go1.7.3 linux/amd64
```

I don't know what `goamz` version I have, but I am very sure that I am on the tip of master.

Comment: The code works fine for me. I get the other attributes present in the table in printing result.

Comment: @notionquest, Thank You. I am certainly not getting the other attributes. I wonder what I am doing differently from you...

Comment: could you please share your GO and goamz version?

Comment: @notionquest, I updated my answer, I was not  able to find `goamz` version, but am I very sure that I am on the tip of master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it could be a bug in the **`goamz`** library. The function `parseAttribute` has logic to parse the different data types. However, it looks like it doesn't seems to be working for data types MAP, LIST, BOOL etc.

Per my observation, String, Number and SS data types are working fine. If you can add a **non-key string attribute** and execute the program. You should get the attribute in the result.

[goamz item go source code for reference](https://github.com/AdRoll/goamz/blob/34e96a017307e0442cd8e5f0c15e199c9934563f/dynamodb/item.go)

Comment: Yes, that's is true; I get that result. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I (the OP) ended up using .. [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/tree/master/service/dynamodb)

And it works fine, the code I used:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
)

func main() {

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(endpoints.UsWest2RegionID),
    }))

    svc := dynamodb.New(sess)

    input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "year": {
                N: aws.String("1999"),
            },
            "title": {
                S: aws.String("MyMovie"),
            },
        },
        TableName: aws.String("Movies"),
    }

    result, err := svc.GetItem(input)

    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```